# R function to print negative numbers only

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function in R that a given vector will print only the negative number. I tried the following:

```
Negative_number <- function (i) {
  return(i <0)
}

print(Negative_number(c(-2,1,3,-5)))

[1] TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
```

Instead of true or false, I want to print the actual negative numbers i.e. -2 & -5 in this case. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Use the logical vector as indices to subset your vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, we need to do the subsetting based on the logical vector

```
Negative_number <- function(i) i[i <0]
Negative_number(c(-2,1,3,-5))
#[1] -2 -5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the dplyr::filter function

```
negatives_only <- dplyr::filter(c(-2,1,3,-5), function (x) x < 0)
```

Any element in the input dataset for which the predicate evaluates to true or NA is returned. All other elements are dropped.

Comment: I get an error because `filter` is meant to be used on data frames and you've given it a vector